# How to change value of a cell up to another

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a column in a sheet,
I want to change the value of the cell of another sheet with rules:

1. If the text is: "Won" or "Lost" or "Cancel" Then get these text values into the target cell.
2. Else values then get the value of right above the From cell.
   My syntax like this:
   =if('Weekly Plan'!F5 = "Won" or 'Weekly Plan'!F5 = "Lost" or 'Weekly Plan'!F5 = "Cancel";'Weekly Plan'!F5;'Weekly Plan'!F4)
   But it has given me the error:
   Error
   Formula parses error.
   Invalid:
   Input must fall within the specified range

I don't know how to fix this

Thanks!

Comment: Is it for excel or for google sheets? Please fix the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

`=IF(OR(F5="Won",F5="Lost",F5="Cancel"),F5,F4)`

Answer (score 2):

You seem not to understand the way logical operators work in Excel formulas:

It's not: `A OR B OR C`
But: `OR(A;B;C)`

Or (in case you might need and `AND`-operator):

It's not: `A AND B AND C`
But: `AND(A;B;C)`

Keep out: the semicolon can be replaced by a comma, this is determined by your locale.

Good luck